# Running Xen with Virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, adobe-photoshop, xen

I am researching building a new machine for software development.

My requirements:

- Linux base OS
- Windows 7 VM for Photoshop CS5
- Various Linux VMs for DB server, application server, etc
- No gaming requirements at all
- 4k-ish monitor support (3840 x 2160) in main machine and Win7

I am looking at an AsRock Extreme4 and an Intel i7 4771 since it has Vt-d. Will max it out with 32GB RAM.

I'd like to run my machine at full speed for development and also run a hardware video card for the windows vm. I am looking at getting a Quadro (or hacked GeForce) and dedicating that to Win7 and probably a GeForce for the main machine.

My questions:

- Do I want to run my "main machine" as a Xen guest or Xen host (probably wrong terms there)?
- Would my Win7 machine be in a window (preferred) or would I need to dedicate a monitor to it?
- I am using Genymotion for emulating Android devices. This is based on VirtualBox. Can I run VirtualBox as well as Xen? Would it be best to run that in Xen host or on a Xen guest machine?

My other option is to skip Xen, and just run VirtualBox. However, I don't think I can do VGA passthrough to Win7 in VirtualBox yet, so would have an emulated GPU in Win7. That's the way my old setup was and Photoshop performance was sluggish.

Comment: Might I suggest using KVM instead of XEN.  I believe it has better support for Windows (and requires Linux as the host)